# Баг или фича в javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: Приложение]

Не могу понять что это такое(желтая копия элементов) и как ее убрать? Для чего это нужно, и как это назвать?

Comment: думаю все же фича

Comment: нет это глюк. попробуй ребутнуться. тут непонятно в чем дело. в intellijj или sceneBuilder или еще в чем

Comment: Это называется "маленький желтый прямоугольник на скриншоте, который без лупы не разглядеть, а даже и с лупой ничего понять невозможно"